# PHP String to Valid XML file

Tags: php, xml, dom, formatting

I have a problem converting my string which has a structure of XML into a proper XML file.

My String looks like:

```
<product>
  <ID>12345</ID>
  <NAME></NAME>
</product>
<product>
  <ID>123</ID>
  <NAME></NAME>
</product>
```

And so on. The problem is that I get empty result if I use DOM.

```
$dom = new DomDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadXML($products);
$xml = $dom->saveXML($dom);
```

Output is:

```
string(39) "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
"
```

How can I make this work? Or I just can add the html and root tags to this string and just parse it to the file?

Comment: You don't have a root node in your XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML is not properly formatted. XML requires a root element.

If you change your XML to something like this:

```
<products>
    <product>
      <ID>12345</ID>
      <NAME></NAME>
    </product>
    <product>
      <ID>123</ID>
      <NAME></NAME>
    </product>
</products>
```

It should work as expected.

Adjusted code:

```
<?php
$dom = new DomDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadXML('<products>
    <product>
      <ID>12345</ID>
      <NAME></NAME>
    </product>
    <product>
      <ID>123</ID>
      <NAME></NAME>
    </product>
</products>');
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<products>
    <product>
      <ID>12345</ID>
      <NAME/>
    </product>
    <product>
      <ID>123</ID>
      <NAME/>
    </product>
</products>
```